# Error in passing a structure as a key in multimap

Tags: c++, qt, stl

I am trying to create a multimap using multikey structure as a key and I am getting a error described below:

Code:

```
struct stCont
{
    long long Tok;
    char Reserved;
    long long Asset;
}
struct MultiKey {

    char InstrumentName[6];
    char Symbol[10];
    long long ExpiryDate;
}
std::multimap<MultiKey, stCont> cont_map;
```

error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xfunctional:125: error: C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const MultiKey' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qchar.h(391): could be 'bool operator <(QChar,QChar)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qbytearray.h(538): or       'bool operator <(const QByteArray &,const QByteArray &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qbytearray.h(540): or       'bool operator <(const QByteArray &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qbytearray.h(542): or       'bool operator <(const char *,const QByteArray &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qstring.h(565): or       'bool operator <(const QString &,const QString &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qstring.h(625): or       'bool operator <(const char *,const QString &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qstring.h(632): or       'bool operator <(const char *,const QStringRef &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qstring.h(975): or       'bool operator <(QLatin1String,QLatin1String)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1032): or       'bool operator <(const char *,QLatin1String)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1304): or       'bool operator <(const QStringRef &,const QStringRef &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
while trying to match the argument list '(const MultiKey, const MultiKey)'
```

I have written this code for myComp:

```
struct myComp
    {
       bool operator() (const MultiKey& lhs, const MultiKey& rhs)
       {
           if((lhs.ExpiryDate==rhs.ExpiryDate)&&(memcmp(lhs.InstrumentName,rhs.InstrumentName,6))&&(memcmp(lhs.Symbol,rhs.Symbol,10)))
           {
               return 1;
           }

           return 0;
       }
    };
```

and now  i m getting an error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtree:1546: error: C3848: expression having type 'const myComp' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool myComp::operator ()(const MultiKey &,const MultiKey &)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't define a custom comparator (a compare function) for your `map`

May be like this based on your `ExpiryDate`

```
    struct myComp
    {
       bool operator() (const MultiKey& lhs, const MultiKey& rhs)
       {
           return lhs.ExpiryDate < rhs.ExpiryDate ;
       }
    };
```

And then use:

```
std::multimap<MultiKey, stCont,myComp> cont_map;
```

Comment: @user2617519 after your `MultiKey` structure before creating a `multimap`

Comment: Now i m having another problem con u please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some way to order the keys in the map. By default, this is `std::less<T>` (which redirects to `operator<`, which doesn't exist for your `MultiKey`). You need to create a comparator and pass this in as a template parameter:

```
struct multikey_compare
{
    bool operator()(const MultiKey& a, const MultiKey& b) const
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Then define your `multimap`:

```
std::multimap<MultiKey, stCont, multikey_compare> cont_map;
```

Comment: Now i m having another problem con u please help me

Comment: You need to mark your `operator()` as a `const` function - notice you're missing the `const` at the end of the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` and `std::multimap` requires comparable keys. If you use C++1, you can use `std::unordered_map`/`std::unordered_multimap` if you need incomparable keys. This in turn requires implementing a hashing function. Otherwise, you might want to take look at [`boost::unordered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/unordered.html).

Comment: And `std::unordered_map` requires customized hash function.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you will need to define:

```
bool operator < (const MultiKey& x, const MultiKey& y)
{
    // implement complete order relationship between x and y
}
```

If you define this though, you should also define ==, !=, >, <=, and >= (STL doesn't require more than the < definition, but it is a good idea to do so).